# Problem converting a tagged C union to a Rust enum because of memory layout

Tags: c, rust

I'm  trying to interact with a C event API structured like this:

```c
struct EventA {
    int type;
    int data1;
    int data2;
};

struct EventB {
    int type;
    int data1;
};

union Event {
    int type;
    EventA eventA;
    EventB eventB;
};

//grabs the next event from the queue.
void pollEvent(Event *event);
```

In the C API, the `type` field is used to determine what type of event has occurred. This is essentially a tagged union, or what enums are in Rust. I know Rust allows you choose the underlying tag of the enum with `#[repr(type)]` however I believe Rust doesn't guarantee that the tag is the first field of the enum. (Or is its always the last field?) This makes it kinda gross when converting the API to Rust because I'd need some type of middleman structure to poll then match its type, convert it to a enum, then the user would match the enum.

If I knew the tag was the first field of the enum, I know the enum and the union have the same memory representation, and I could just pass it as pointer.

What I'd like to do:

```
use::std::os::raw::c_int;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct EventA {
    pub data1: c_int,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct EventB {
    pub data1: c_int,
    pub data2: c_int,
}

#[repr(i32)] //I'm assuming c_int is 32 bit.
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Event {
    // <---- Put the tag is here, followed the union memory, 
    A(EventA),
    B(EventB),
}

extern {
    pub fn pollEvents(*mut Event);
}

pub fn poll_events(*mut Event) {
    unsafe {
        pollEvents(*mut Event);
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that the tag will come after the data fields, and `#[repr(C)]` for a enum only changes what integer type the tag is

Comment: I deleted my comments because I have only just realised what you are actually asking!

Comment: There *are* actually unions in rust, see [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html)

Comment: @hellow OP knows that. He is saying that, somehow, his C unions are laid out exactly like a Rust enum so he wants to do the conversion directly.

Comment: However, I think that a `union` is still the best fit. It can be mapped to an `enum` with practically zero overhead.

Comment: I'd rather not use a union here because they require unsafe blocks, although if there isn't any other way it may be the way I go.

Comment: You need unsafe blocks for FFI anyway...

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you can only use `Copy` types in a union with stable rust. To use non-copy types you have to use nightly with `#![feature(untagged_unions)]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2195-really-tagged-unions.md#guide-level-explanation) that guarantees some layout when you use `#[repr(C, Int)]` on an enum that basically allows what you want. Note that, as always, Rust only does the best guess, and you should add tests for memory layout at compile time.